# how to get the session values on to my web page

Tags: php, session-cookies

I added 3 cookies using php `setcookie` function and i can see them in my browser cookie data, but when i call them on my page, they are not displaying on my page.

For example I saw in my browser data that there are 15 cookies set for my site which includes my 3 cookies but when i do `var_dump($_COOKIE)` on my page it just displays 8 cookies and not showing my 3 cookies, can anyone tell me how can i get them on to my page.

this is how i set cookie's:

```
setcookie("useremail", $email);
setcookie("username", $name);
setcookie("userid", $uid);
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear that you aren't making a daft mistake - these set cookies are sent with the response headers.  The request headers at the time didn't come with any cookie data because they hadn't previously been set... have you tried reloading the page?

Comment: yes, i tried but of no use.. i didnt see any output on my page

Comment: are you trying to set the cookies after you have already sent headers?  IE. if any HTML output is mixed in with your code above `setcookie` it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `print_r($_COOKIE);` to show all cookies

or `echo $_COOKIE["useremail"];` to show only useremail

Answer (score 0):

This is how we get the cookies value in page:It should work.

```
$email=$_COOKIE['useremail'];
$username=$_COOKIE['username'];
$userid=$_COOKIE['userid'];
```

Comment: no these values are not showing on my page, but they are showing in the browser's cookie data

Comment: On top of your php page add: session_start();

Comment: Also add ob_start(); on top of your page.